# INotifyPropertyChanged/Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, win-universal-app

I am trying to figure out how to update my main UI (for example a textblock) from another thread.  The only way I have been able to do it so far is using the Progress object.  I have a situation where I cannot use the Progress object and I was recently pointed to using the MVVM / binding method.  I have watch a few videos and done some examples but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<TextBlock Name="txtblock1" Text="{Binding count}"></TextBlock>
```

Here are my errors

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in
>   System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll

View (Code behind)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModelexample obj = new ViewModelexample();
        txtblock1.DataContext = obj;
        obj.Methodasync();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelexample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string count { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler !=null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public async void Methodasync()
    {
        await Method();         
    }

    public Task Method()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                count = i.ToString();
                onPropertyChanged(i.ToString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Your view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but you need to have the count properly actually raise the event. I can post sample code if you need. I'm on a phone so a little hard right now.

Comment: Also, don't call async methods from a constructor. Use the OnNavigatedTo event or have some other event like a button click call the async method.

Comment: `propertyName` needs to be the name of the property being changed (i.e., `count`), so the last line of your `for` loop should instead be `onPropertyChanged(nameof(count));`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am still getting the same error after changing opPropertyChanged(nameof(count))

Comment: ManOvision I would really appreciate when you have the time.

Comment: @user3363744 what version of .Net are you using. the tag says c#4 but there is also win universal app

Comment: I would look into the Mediator pattern, or EventAggregator pattern to solve your communication between background threads and UI thread. Basically, if you set up a subscriber on your UI thread that can invoke INotifyPropertyChanged, then all you need is to post a message from any background thread to fire it, and your problem is solved. I know PRISM used to carry an IEventAggregator, but I am not sure wether this is available for UWP, so some research may be needed.

Comment: I am writing this in a universal app Nkosi

Comment: I was under the assumption that binding would take care of the cross threading call.

Answer (score 3):

Your `count` Property needs to be able to notify that it has changed

```
public class ViewModelexample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    private string _count;
    public string count { 
        get { return _count; } 
        set {
            if(value != _count) {
                _count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(count));
            }
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // the new Null-conditional Operators are thread-safe:
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int _testCount = 0;
    public void Method() {
        testCount++;
        Debug.WriteLine(testCount.ToString());
        count = testCount.ToString();
    }

}
```

The above works because the new Null-conditional Operators are [thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595):

> Another use for the null-condition member access is invoking delegates
>   in a thread-safe way with much less code. ... The new way is
>   thread-safe because the compiler generates code to evaluate
>   PropertyChanged one time only, keeping the result in a temporary
>   variable.

To Test it you can edit your ViewModel method and have the view call it on an event like on page loaded or a button click.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page 
{
    ViewModelexample obj = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        obj = new ViewModelexample();
        this.DataContext = obj;        
    }

    public void OnSomeEventHandler() {
        obj.Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I get the same error with your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I tried the new code and I still get the same errors.  It errors as soon as it gets to the line onPropertyChanged(nameof(count))

Answer (score 2):

> I was under the assumption that binding would take care of the cross threading call.

No, this is only true for *some* MVVM frameworks (such as WPF). For this reason, I prefer to treat all my ViewModels as belonging to the UI.

With your code sample, you should be able to use `Progress<T>`:

```
public async void Methodasync()
{
  var progress = new Progress<int>(value =>
  {
    count = value;
    onPropertyChanged("count");
  });
  await Method(progress);
}

public Task Method(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  return Task.Run(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
      Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());
      progress.Report(i);
    }
  });
}
```

Also note that I changed from `StartNew` to `Run`. As a general rule, don't use `StartNew` for [reasons I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

If you "really for serious" cannot use `Progress<T>` for some odd reason, then you can use Reactive Extensions or `SynchronizationContext` directly.

Example using `SynchronizationContext`:

```
public Task Method()
{
  var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  return Task.Run(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
      Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());
      var localI = i;
      context.Post(() =>
      {
        count = localI;
        onPropertyChanged("count");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The `localI` thing is to [avoid closing over the loop variable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

Comment: The reason I can't use Progress is because I am using the StreamSocket library for my TCP server application.  I can't pass the Progress object into the ClientConnection event.  Is there a way to pass the progress object into a class event?

Comment: Also, where did "current" come from?  I am unable to use current.Post(().  Thank you for the info.

Comment: @user3363744: "current" was a typo; should have been `context`. I still don't understand why you can't just call `IProgress<T>.Report` from your event handler.

Comment: I cant figure out how to pass the Progress object through the event handler. --serverListener.ConnectionReceived += ClientConnected;

Comment: also the context.Post gives a error under Post that says there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameters 'stat' of  SynchronizationContext.Post(sendorpostcallback, post)

Comment: Is there a way to pass the Progress object to the ConnectionReceived event?

Comment: @user3363744: Something like `ConnectionReceived += (_, __) => { progress.Report(whatever); };`